# What is Vorlander's rule?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is Vorlander's rule? I have got it from a book all of a sudden, but without any further information about it; could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Did you googled? https://books.google.pl/books?id=CRgSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=Vorlander%27s+rule&source=bl&ots=1NEobHpute&sig=MWubdrWgiH4yDfviMgZq8tS9K14&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTqYWx2cbaAhXRsaQKHTzpD7cQ6AEINDAJ#v=onepage&q=Vorlander's%20rule&f=false

Comment: Also such "rule" seems rather part of _history_ of chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

Vorlander's rule discuss about the directing powers of substituent present in benzene ring. Taken [from here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nYDl4kO4HKUC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=vorlander%20rule&source=bl&ots=NGaxf-RNnk&sig=fPRjSNUu3hYkSqB-SPiBA_3Qh_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2-uS2hcfaAhULq48KHXQ_CXYQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=vorlander%20rule&f=false):

> 1. Saturated groups (containing single bonds) direct predominately 2- and 4-positions.
> 2. Unsaturated groups (containing multiple bonds) direct predominately at 3-positions.

[Here are some examples:](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Zy6-ahRQ054C&pg=SL15-PA432&lpg=SL15-PA432&dq=vorlander%20rule&source=bl&ots=VCGo16GCW8&sig=5oRylgL0o19qR0pGsZc-V2RmDo0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2-uS2hcfaAhULq48KHXQ_CXYQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=vorlander%20rule&f=false)

[image]